# Project has no project.properties file

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent, eclipse-plugin

I am developing Android app in Eclipse.

Currently, eclipse complains:

`"Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one."`

But I **do have** `project.properties` file under my project root folder. Why it complains?

This problem causes several of the resources in `R.java` can not be resolved in **Activity**. 
How to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Right click on project -->Android Tools-->Fix Project Properties.....
```

Comment: I realize this is an old comment, but that did not fix it for me.

Comment: Just create a new project.properties file by copying an existing one from another project and adapting it to your needs. This is a bug in the Eclipse Android plugin, or in Eclipse, that has been around for years now.

Comment: Right clicking on project->Android Tools->Fix Project Properties does nothing

Comment: I had this happen when I mistakenly added Project.Properties to the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 12):

Sometime the 'Fix Project properties...' is not useful.
I suggest that you can open that file and edit+save it, then delete the 'project.properties' file.
At last you can create a new 'project.properties' file and paste the content of the old 'project.properties' file's content.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer *may* had the problem solved a few years ago but it *doesn't* work anymore with the more recent tools.

This is a known bug on Eclipse.

The only way to solve this problem is by creating again a `project.properties` file, which no one posted how it looks inside so I'll be posting this as an answer:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-19
```

> Please note: set the correct target API for your project.

Answer (score 3):

Generally Android Tools-->Fix Project Properties should work. but it didn't solve my problem. I had just delete project from from workspace and import again second time no problem..

Answer (score 1):

properties->Android lint preferences -> ignore all ->make a clean and build  -> properties->Android lint prefrences -> include all

Comment: Please explain your answer instead of just giving it.

Answer (score 1):

In case, you are importing new project from file folder, import this project as general project, not as Android project (I can not tell you why). After import, edit `project.properties` file, just add some character, then save the file. Now Eclipse recognizes `project.properties` file. Repair it(remove added character) and now the project should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens after importing from archive, I suggest to remove the project for the workspace and import it again. That was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the project already contains a file default.properties you can open that file and edit+save it (add a space, save, remove that space, save). That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Right click project -> Properties -> Java Build path -> Order and Export -> check the checkbox of Andorid 4.3.

Comment: Hi and welcome, could you please add some explanation as to how your answer would help this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check file encoding. Apparently UTF-BOM is way too hard for whatever part of Eclipse-SDK is responsible for handling that project.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

i have same issue, simple way is

RightClick project file--> new --> file -->filename type file name as project.properties and --> finish -->  inside project.propeties file type this target=android-17(your virsion of android)

then all errors go away