# Project has no project.properies file

Tags: android

I get the following error messages when tryint to run my project.  Google-play-services seem to be otherwise correctly installed:

> [2014-03-12 14:43:10 - PRS] Project has no project.properties file!
>   Edit the project properties to set one. [2014-03-12 14:43:11 -
>   google-play-services_lib] Project has no project.properties file! Edit
>   the project properties to set one.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties... that is your best bet, but if not you need to adapt an existing property file to your current project. This is a known bug with eclipse, unfortunately.
[Project has no project.properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533061/project-has-no-project-properties-file)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in eclipse. Follow these steps-:

**1.** Copy the data inside project.properties file.

**2.** Delete project.properties file.

**3.** create a new file with name project.properties.

**4.** paste the data inside it.