# Upgrade Mobilefirst CLI 6.3.0 to 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

Are there any known issues in upgrading mobilefirst 6.3 CLI to mobilefirst 7.0 CLI ?

Auto-upgrade fails with the following error in ubuntu 14.0.x, where it was previously working just fine with 6.3.0.

Error when running mfp build -dd

```
mobilefirst-cli verb cli process.argv=["/opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/IBMnode/bin/node","/opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/bin/mobilefirst-cli.js","build","-dd"]
mobilefirst-cli verb cli opts={"ddebug":true,"argv":{"remain":["build"],"cooked":["build","--ddebug"],"original":["build","-dd"]}}
mobilefirst-cli verb cli mobilefirst@7.0.0.00.20150312-0738
mobilefirst-cli verb cli node@v0.10.30
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dbasedir=/home/ubuntu/xxxxxxxxx
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.jars.dir=/opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.ant.tools.dir=/opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/ant-tools
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -Dworklight.hostname=x.x.x.x
mobilefirst-cli verb ant variables -file=/opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml
mobilefirst-cli verb ant task upgrade
Buildfile: /opt/ibm/MobileFirst-CLI/mobilefirst-cli/node_modules/generator-worklight-server/lib/build.xml

upgrade:
[project-upgrader] FINE: DEBUG_PERFORM_UPGRADE
[project-upgrader] INFO: FWLST1022I: Starting to migrate the xxxxxx project from version 6.3.0.00.20150106-1717 to version 7.0.0.00.20150312-0731.

[project-upgrader] path found:6.3.0.0--->7.0.0.0
[project-upgrader] FINE: DEBUG_FOUND_PATH
[project-upgrader] ERROR: Unexpected error during upgrade: java.lang.NullPointerException
[project-upgrader]  at com.worklight.upgrader.upgraders.android.AppAndroidProGuardConfUpgrader.upgrade(AppAndroidProGuardConfUpgrader.java:57)
[project-upgrader]  at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.executeUpgrader(WLUpgradeEngine.java:368)
[project-upgrader]  at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.performUpgrade(WLUpgradeEngine.java:301)
[project-upgrader]  at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.upgradeProject(WLUpgradeEngine.java:188)
[project-upgrader]  at com.worklight.upgrader.ant.UpgraderTask.execute(UpgraderTask.java:100)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
[project-upgrader]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
[project-upgrader]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[project-upgrader]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
[project-upgrader]  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

Comment: Can you provide a MFP 6.3 sample project that reproduces this error when used in MFP 7.0, so that it could be debugged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the upgrade issue using the CLI is being investigated under the APAR PI37526, you can open a PMR to follow it.

The error may also happen if the android\native folder is missing the project.properties file. Verify whether this file exists or doesn't exist in the android\native folder of your MFP project.

You can regenerate this file using the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533061/project-has-no-project-properties-file) or via Google ADT's commandline tool.

As a workaround, you can import the 6.3 project into a MobileFirst *Studio* v7.0; I can at least confirm that when using the Studio the upgrade error mentioned in the question does not happen and the ProGuard files are being added to the upgraded project.

Comment: This error is gone temporarily removing the android target but raises error in iPhone target under nativeResources folder. It says migration failed because of a file xxxx.h. I'm confused, can you please suggest a workaround.

Comment: I have previously asked for your project to reproduce the error but you have ignored my request. No, I can't further help you w/out a project that reproduces the error. If you are an IBM customer then you can open a PMR and supply your project there if you don't want to upload it

Comment: oops did not see that, its not ignored. Let me provide, few mins pls

Comment: I think I should raise a PMR, this is not reproducible except for that project.  What you have suggested for android is right as there was .properties file was filtered in a gitignore by mistake. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: There is already a fix ready for the missing file so you should simply ask for it if you require it (mention this question in the PMR).